# Compiler chooses single type template through multiple types specified

Tags: c++, templates

Since there is no `template<typename T, typename T> ... is_same` declaration, why the compiler doesn't give an error or at least choose `template<typename T, typename U> is_same` when `is_same<int, int>` is used?

1. Shouldn't number of types used in `<>` match a template with same number of types?
2. The `template<typename T, typename U> ... is_same` doesn't have brackets after `is_same` token, so why does the compiler still generate `... is_same<int, float> = false` with brackets?

**CODE**

```
template<typename T, typename U>
constexpr bool is_same = false;

template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_same<T,T> = true;

int main()
{
  std::cout << is_same<int, int>;
  std::cout << is_same<int, float>;
}
```

**COMPILER OUTPUT**

```
template<typename T, typename U>
constexpr const bool is_same = false;

template<>
constexpr const bool is_same<int, int> = true;
template<>
constexpr const bool is_same<int, float> = false;

template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_same<T,T> = true;

int main()
{
  std::cout.operator<<(is_same<int, int>);
  std::cout.operator<<(is_same<int, float>);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"I would expect the compiler to give an error when `is_same<int, int>`..."* Why? There is clearly an explicit specialization `is_same<T,T>` available for it that can be used for `is_same<int, int>`. I would recommend referring to a [beginner c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) that explains the basics of what are specializations and where and how they can be used.

Comment: I changed the wording. But, that's why I'm asking. I didn't understand that part. Can you explain please? When I use `is_same<int, int>` the compiler looks for token `is_same` that has brackets after it, right? How does it choose `is_same` without brackets for `is_same<int, float>`?

Comment: Basically, There is a primary template available that has two template parameters and so when you wrote `is_same<int, int>` the compiler compares the two arguments(which are `int` and `int`) against all the available specializations and then it found a specialization that has both the parameter same and so it chooses that specialization.

Comment: But, how does it generate `is_same<int, float> = false` for `is_same<int, float>`? The template is `bool is_same` and not `bool is_same<...>`

Comment: Because when you write `is_same<int, float>` the "primary template" is the only viable option.

Comment: So, shouldn't it have generated `template<> constexpr const bool is_same = false;` and not `template<> constexpr const bool is_same<int, float> = false;`?

Comment: No because `is_same` is a template-name while `is_same<int, float>` is the actual type and a type-name. **That means `is_same<int, int>` and `is_same<int, float>` are two different classes.**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253870/discussion-between-theateist-and-jason).

Comment: Btw you're using [partial specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization) and not explicit specialization. I mistyped that in my previous comments.